# what folders are trusted when using RemotedSigned

Tags: powershell

Does any one how to tell what folders are trusted when the ExecutionPolicy is set to RemotedSigned? I want to run a number of Powershell script of our network share (which is not mapped, hence using the full unc), but i do not want to have to digitally signed them all.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We have done this in the past by adding a registry key under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\EscDomains that names the server where the share resides.  Under the EscDomains key, add a key that is the server name.  Under that key, add a DWORD value with the name "file" and the value 2.

You need to do this on each machine that will run scripts from the server, but you can do that via group policy.  There are security implications to this beyond running PowerShell scripts.  I don't know if this will work if your computers are not in a domain.  If there are better solutions, I look forward to learning about them.

For more information, see [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569).

Answer (score 0):

So, what happens when you run a script from UNC Path?

With RemoteSigned, you should be able to run all scripts written & run locally without a digital signature.

```
    RemoteSigned
        - Scripts can run.

        - Requires a digital signature from a trusted
          publisher on scripts and configuration files that
          are downloaded from the Internet (including
          e-mail and instant messaging programs).

        - Does not require digital signatures on scripts that you have run
          and that you have written on the local computer (not
          downloaded from the Internet).

        - Risks running unsigned scripts from sources other
          than the Internet and signed, but malicious, scripts.

    Unrestricted
        - Unsigned scripts can run. (This risks running malicious
          scripts.)

        - Warns the user before running srcipts and configuration
          files that are downloaded from the Internet.
```